# Why am I getting 'name is not defined'

Tags: python

I'm struggling to understand why this gives me name 'month' is not defined

I'm trying to convert input(10, 5, 2017) to October 5, 2017 for example

```
def problem3_3(month, day, year):
months_tuple = ('January', 'February', 'March','April', 'May', 'June', 
'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')

A = months_tuple[month-1]
B = str(day)
C = str(year)

print("A", +"B,"+"C")
```

Comment: Is your code indented properly? If it looks exactly like in your question that will be a problem.

Comment: `print("A", +"B,"+"C")` does not make sense.  Do you mean `print(A, B, C)`?

Comment: Your example code doesn't call the `problem3_3()` function, so what line is giving you causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your code have indentation problem in the function and in the print statement, you don't need to put A, B and C between " " because they are string already. That should work:

```
def problem3_3(month, day, year):
    months_tuple = ('January', 'February', 'March','April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')

    A = months_tuple[month-1]
    B = str(day)
    C = str(year)

    print(A + ", " + B + ", " + C)

problem3_3(10, 5, 2017)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice, it was indeed the indentation that was the problem. I am clearly very new at this :)